# Pictures and Menus aren't loading correctly on certain CNN pages, ABC

Tags: google-chrome, browser, pictures

Loading content from CNN on my windows 7 computer, and the images/menus on some webpages do not appear correct. (e.g., [CNN and ABC page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVE3K.png))

Other pages seem fine (e.g., [CNN homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKrAg.jpg))

I'm running an up-to-date chrome (tried on regular chrome and incognito), and I've also tried it in IE (also up-to-date) - the webpages appear similarly wonky on both browsers.

I've already tried the following remedies:

1. Restart browser.
2. Restart machine.
3. Clear internet data (Cache, Cookies, Offline Website Data, Authenticated Sessions) using CCleaner
4. Unchecked and checked "Prefetch resources to load pages more quickly" setting
5. Disabling all add-ons and restarting browser.
6. Reinstalling browser.
7. Flash and Shockwave are up-to-date

None of these have helped.

Questions:

Any other ideas of what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Update Java - I had the exact same problem on Win7 w/ Chrome and IE until I updated.